# How to select the integer and float values from every rows?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame that consists of strings, float, and integers in every row?
I need to extract all the integer and float values from right to left until the alphabet occurs?
The data frame (`df1`) is

```
df1:
    text
0   NS-100ML(GLASS) IV 1 19.25
1   India 560 into SI  10  63.26
2   INJ 2 914.20
```

I need `df1` output like

```
df1:
    text
0   [1,   19.25]
1   [10,  63.26]
2   [2,   914.20]
```

Note: Please don't suggest me to take last two split strings, bcs my next data frame (`df2`) looks different as below,

```
df2:
    text
0   NS-100ML(GLASS) IV 1.00 4.95 63.36 96.45
1   India into 456 SI  8.0 52.30 53.46 12.03
2   INJ 2.0 63.80 34.30 56.36
```

I df2 output like

```
df2:
    text
0   [1.0, 4.95,  63.36, 96.45]
1   [8.0, 52.30, 53.46, 12.03]
2   [2.0, 63.80, 34.30, 56.36]
```

Eventually, I need to extract all the float and integers from right to left (different data frames can have different length of integer and floats)

Comment: Maybe `df['text2'] = df['text'].str.findall(r'\d{,3}\.\d{,3}')` assuming there are no more than three digits before or after the period. change 'text2' to 'text' if you want to overwrite the column but a new column may be good for testing.

Comment: Your first sentence need to be more precise (and not a question :-|), such as (if my understand is correct) "I have a data frame containing rows beginning with one or more digits, followed by spaces, followed by a string of characters, the last of which is not a digit, followed by the string representations of floats and/or integers separated by spaces."

Comment: You still need to clarify your question (ref my previous comment), in part because you owe to it the many SO members who will read your question in future.

Comment: You added numbers within the string of words after answers had been posted. That changed the question materially, rendering answers incorrect and even nonsensical. You obviously cannot do that. I'm surprised that wasn't obvious to you. Please roll back your question to before that edit. You can ask another question if you like.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP materially changed the question after several answers have been posted, making the answers incorrect. The OP was asked to roll-back to the original question but has not done so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the string methods `replace` and `split` for pandas Series. Note that dot(`.`) within square brackets means literal dot.

```
df1['text'].str.extract("( [0-9 .]+)$", expand=False).str.split()

0    [1, 19.25]
1    [10, 63.26]
2    [2, 914.20]


df2['text'].str.extract("( [0-9 .]+)$", expand=False).str.split()

0    [1.00, 4.95, 63.36, 96.45]
1    [8.0, 52.30, 53.46, 12.03]
2    [2.0, 63.80, 34.30, 56.36]
```

**Additional example from comments**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text':['NEOVEC INJ 385251 APR/2021 5.00 89.00 445.00']})

df['text'].str.extract("( [0-9 .]+)$", expand=False).str.split()

0    [5.00, 89.00, 445.00]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for solution,
What if I have the numbers in between the words? I don't want to pick them.
Kindly check the question again.

Comment: If you have any number before the last letter/word (or between two words), it will be canceled out. In the second row of your df2, you have a number between the words
(`India into 456 SI  8.0 52.30 53.46 12.03` and `456` is between `into`
and `SI`) and it's been canceled. Is it clear?

Comment: But it fails for following data `NEOVEC INJ 385251 APR/2021 5.00 89.00 445.00`
here I need only `5.00 89.00 445.00` as per the question.

Comment: Yeah, It's working. if you don't mind, Could you pls expain the regex pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Try a combination of apply with regex,

```
df1['text'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x.split() if not re.match('[A-Za-z\W]', i)])

0     [1, 19.25]
1    [10, 63.26]
2    [2, 914.20]


df2['text'].apply(lambda x: [i for i in x.split() if not re.match('[A-Za-z\W]', i)])


0    [1.00, 4.95, 63.36, 96.45]
1    [8.0, 52.30, 53.46, 12.03]
2    [2.0, 63.80, 34.30, 56.36]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for solution,
What if I have the numbers in between the words? I don't want to pick them.
Kindly check the question again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the regex:

```
^(\d+)\s+.*\D\s+(?=((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?\s*)+)$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/4qxLMU/1/)

with the multiline flag set (or insert `(?m)` at beginning).

For the row (for example)

```
0   NS-100ML(GLASS) IV 1 19.25
```

capture group 1 will contain `0` and capture group 2 will contain `1 19.25`. It should be an easy matter to replace the row with the desired string derived from the contents of the two capture groups.

Python's regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^                # match beginning of line
(\d+)            # match 1+ digits in cap grp 1
\s+              # match 1+ spaces
.*               # match 0+ chars
\D               # match a char other than a digit
\s+              # match 1+ spaces
(?=              # begin positive lookahead
  (              # begin cap grp 2
    (?:          # begin non-cap grp
      \d+        # match 1+ digits
      (?:\.\d+)  # match '.' followed by 1+ digits in non-cap grp
      ?          # optionally match non-cap grp
      \s*        # match 0+ spaces
    )            # end non-cap grp
    +            # match non-cap grp 1+ times
  )              # end cap grp 2
  $              # match end of line
)                # end positive lookahead
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for solution,
What if I have the numbers in between the words? I don't want to pick them.
Kindly check the question again.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that numbers are separated by a single space. If you had a single row, I would use:

```
def extract_numbers(row):
    entries = row['text'].split(' ')
    ans = []
    while entries:
        item = entries.pop()
        try:
            num = float(item)
        except ValueError:
            # we encountered non-numerical data
            return ans
        else:
            ans = [num] + ans
   return ans
```

Now you have a dataframe.

```
df['numbers'] = df['text'].apply(extract_numbers)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method using `str.split` and `explode`

```
print(df2)

                                       text
0  NS-100ML(GLASS) IV 1.00 4.95 63.36 96.45
1      India into SI  8.0 52.30 53.46 12.03
2                INJ 2.0 63.80 34.30 56.36 


number_list = pd.to_numeric(df2["text"].str.split(" ").explode(), errors="coerce").dropna().groupby(
    level=0
).agg(list)
```

---

```
print(number_list)

0    [1.0, 4.95, 63.36, 96.45]
1    [8.0, 52.3, 53.46, 12.03]
2     [2.0, 63.8, 34.3, 56.36]
Name: text, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for solution,
What if I have the numbers in between the words? I don't want to pick them.
Kindly check the question again.